# JPA: How to save from flux in reactive repository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-webflux

Given a repository that extends `ReactiveCrudRepository`:

```
interface PersonRepo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    // ...
}
```

and a Person data class with Name and Age

```
class Person { ... }
```

Should this client code not save my persons to the repository?

```
private void savePeople() {
    Person p1 = new Person(23L, "p1", 22);
    Person p2 = new Person(25L, "p2", 39);
    List<Person> peoples = new ArrayList<>();
    peoples.add(p1);
    peoples.add(p2);
    personRepository.saveAll(Flux.fromIterable(peoples));
}
```

I can't find `p1` or `p2` in the H2 in-memory database. Why not?

Comment: No, since you are returning void so that the calling client cant subscribe to the Mono that gets returned. Return from the database call all the way out to the calling client and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

change you method signature to `private Mono<Void> savePeople()`

and then replace `personRepository.saveAll(Flux.fromIterable(peoples))` with following

```
return personRepository.saveAll(Flux.fromIterable(peoples)).then();
```

last statement is not going to be invoked until you subscribe to saveAll method returned Flux. follow above steps. you will see p1 & p2 in DB